# WooCommerce batch update/create webhooks not working

Tags: php, woocommerce, laravel-5.6

WooCommerce batch update webhooks not working.

I am trying to create webhooks programatically using the WooCommerce's Rest API with Laravel library( https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce).

I can successfully can retrieve orders, products etc . But unable to create batch webhook which is menction [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-webhooks).

Here is the php script that I have written:

```
$data = [
    'create' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Round toe',
        'topic' => 'coupon.created',
        'delivery_url' => 'http://requestb.in/1g0sxmo1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Customer deleted',
        'topic' => 'customer.deleted',
        'delivery_url' => 'http://requestb.in/1g0sxmo1'
    ]],
    'delete' => [
        143
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('webhooks/batch', $data));
```

Here is th error message that i got from woocommerce api.

> { "error": "Error: No route was found matching the URL and request 
>   method [woocommerce_api_no_route]"
>
> }